# How do I reboot from the recovery console?

Tags: reboot, password-recovery, recovery-mode

I run Ubuntu in a virtual machine and I've managed to reset my password in recovery mode, by editing the parameters according to [these instructions on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/419277/sudo-must-be-setuid-root-error-and-recovery-mode-requires-root-passwd). Summarizing my steps:

I changed `ro single` at the end of the line beginning with `Linux` to `rw init=/bin/bash`, while booting, then using the command `passwd <username>`, entered the new password twice. The password is reported to be updated successfully.

However, when I try to reboot the system nothing happens. I tried the command `reboot`, but it does not work. If I type `exit` I get kernel panic.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: can you try `sudo shutdown -h now` and `sudo reboot`?

Comment: Thanks. I get "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)" from both of those commands.

Comment: can you type `hostname`?

Comment: hostname gives me "(none)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `telinit 6` you don't need sudo since your in `single user mode`.

EDIT:

If it wont reboot using the standard tools there is a way to do it straight through to the kernel, however this does not close file systems nicely.

Found this [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way)

> you must activate the magic SysRq option:
>
> ```
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
> ```
>
> When you are ready to reboot the machine simply run the following:
>
> ```
> echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
> ```
>
> This does not attempt to unmount or sync filesystems, so it should
>   only be used when absolutely necessary..

Comment: When I do init 6 I get " Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused"

Comment: @forumuser update answer try this one.

Comment: I'm afraid I get the same error message

Comment: @forumuser how strange.... edited again.

Comment: The echo to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` sounds the same as pressing ctrl+alt+[key] and pressing keys R E I S U B (with a few seconds between each, all with ctrl+alt) should try to end all processes, sync filesystems (most important), remount as ro, and reboot.